# How do I enable support for dbm (php)?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php and coding in general. I'm trying to enable support for dbm but not sure how to go about it and I did not find a lot by googling. I've read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dba.installation.php) that tells me to use the **--enable-dba=shared** configuration option but I don't know where to find it. I've added the configurations to **dba.default_handler=** in the php.ini file but that does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to enable support for dba on here?

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini you need to add or if it is already present, remove the comment `;` in order to enable the extension:

`extension=php_dba.dll`

(Make sure that you have `php_dba.dll` file in your php folder located in the `ext` directory)

Then in your php file you can add:

`phpinfo();`

which will print a log and show you a list of information where there should be a log saying that it is enabled, something like this:
[image]

Comment: The php.ini setting is just `extension=php_dba`. DLL files are a Windows thing, the question made no mention of Windows.

Comment: @miken32 I assumed that it is on windows. If it is linux or unix based, it will still be the same steps, apart from the dll file location, it would rather be ```sudo apt-get install php*.*-dba``` where ```*.*``` should be version number e.g. 7.0 or whichever is stable.

Comment: If it's a Debian-based Linux, sure.

Comment: Thank you people! I've now added the extension and it shows up when calling "phpinfo()). However, I'm still not sure how to install the handlers? I want to use Oracle Berkeley 4 (db4). Also, yes I'm on Windows, forgot that part!

Comment: In the php documentation it says: 
"The behaviour of various aspects depends on the implementation of the underlying database. Functions such as dba_optimize() and dba_sync() will do what they promise for one database and will do nothing for others. You have to download and install supported dba-Handlers." https://www.php.net/manual/en/dba.requirements.php
B4
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-downloads.html

I found a guide that might be of use :
https://www.lampdocs.com/adding-dba-support-to-php/
else I encourage others to try to answer the question